# Perl - Loop SSH command with line by line variable

Tags: perl, ssh

I want to run a command over SSH and make it loop until my variable has read all the lines from a file .

I have this :

```
$channel = $ssh->channel();
$channel->exec('echo -n "$command"') 
$channel->exec('rest of commands')
```

What I need to do is to run that `echo` command with the variable being each line from my local file `/home/variables` in a loop.

It should keep looping the `echo` command until all the lines from my file are finished before it moves to the rest of the script.

I thought I should use something like :

```
open my $enable, '<', '/home/variables';

while (my $command = <$enable>) {
chomp $command;
$channel->exec("echo -n $command");
last;
$channel->exec('next command');
```

It's not really looping though .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#-- creating a channel
my $channel = $ssh->channel();
$channel->shell();

open my $enable, '<', 'x1';

while (my $command = <$enable>) {
  $channel->write( $command );
  }

$channel->write( $final_command );
```

Also note that you need a newline after each command so I left out the chomp.

From the [`Net::SSH2` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2::Channel#exec-command) :

"Note that only one of these requests can succeed per channel (cp. "exec" in perlfunc); if you want to run a series of commands, consider using shell instead."

I hope that helps.